# ¿Qué hacer cuando un usuario al que respondí una pregunta, edita la pregunta y la cambia totalmente?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, ediciones

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116846/47499) publicación trato de responder la pregunta del OP, el cual originalmente estaba buscando una solución para su `barnav` de Bootstrap, una vez respondí la pregunta, el OP me dijo que si le funcionó pero que tuvo un error al formular la pregunta, y luego metió más código referente a unas barras laterales. ¿Qué se debe hacer en estos casos? ¿Debo reportar la pregunta, o pedirle que haga otra pregunta con el segundo problema?

Comment: Gracias @sstan por tu intervención :)

Comment: Yo le pediría que marcara esta pregunta como resuelta, marcando tu respuesta como correcta (si lo era) y que creara una pregunta nueva referenciando a la anterior. Al fin y al cabo, preguntar es gratis, ¿no? :)

Comment: Parece que el usuario comenta que ya hizo una nueva pregunta y aceptó la tuya como respuesta correcta. Si hace falta revertir la pregunta a un estado anterior, podemos hacerlo

Comment: Así es fedorqui y Alvaro Montoto, el usuario comentó que ya realizó una nueva pregunta. Esta pregunta ya tiene varios días que fue formulada y contestada, gracias por su intervención. Y me parece muy buen punto el que José Antonio Dura Olmos comenta, más que ayudar al OP, se trata de ayudar a otros usuarios, por lo que la pregunta debería permanecer en el estado original en la cual fue formulada.

Comment: Eso lo hacen mucho. Hay un usuario al que respondí hace poco que ha modificado y editado tanto la pregunta que me han votado negativo "porque la respuesta no tiene nada que ver". Normal, yo respondí hace 15 versiones de la pregunta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pídele que haga otra pregunta con el segundo problema y que restaure la pregunta a la situación anterior.

Si no lo hace en un tiempo razonable márcala para atención de moderador.

La edición de preguntas se debe usar para mejorarlas. Por ejemplo incluyendo aclaraciones sobre lo que se pregunta, un ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable, datos de entrada y/o resultado esperado. No deben editarse para cambiar el significado de la pregunta.

Una buena pregunta debe tener una utilidad que supera a la de ayudar a quien la formula. Debe ser útil para otras personas, por eso es importante que permanezca después de haber sido resuelta. Para que otras personas en el futuro con la misma duda puedan encontrar la solución.